# Bubble text canvas effect as background

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html5-canvas, frontend

I have found a beautiful background text effect, and have no idea what is the key word for it. Can anyone help me? Here's the link, the effect I mentioned is on the top of the website "Good Innovation"
http://www.dentsu.com.vn

[image]

Comment: aint loading, could you post screnshot or rehost page somewhere?

Comment: Just added a pic, it's more beautiful when move is moved over.